# Can I reduce the delay between video frames?

Tags: framerate

I have a variable frame rate video file. There is a delay of over 30 seconds between some frames. Can I transcode the video and reduce all delays between frames over a certain value, say 1 second, to that value? This would mean the maximum gap or delay between any 2 consecutive frames would be 1 second.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with ffmpeg. I ended up using following:

```
ffmpeg -i input-file -vf "setpts=ifnot(isnan(PREV_OUTPTS)\,PREV_OUTPTS) + min(1000\,PTS - PREV_INPTS)" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 output.mkv
```

You can print expressions like this, which is useful for testing:

```
ffmpeg -i input-file -vf "setpts=print(PREV_INPTS)\;print(PTS - PREV_INPTS)\;print(ifnot(isnan(PREV_OUTPTS)\,PREV_OUTPTS) + min(1000\,PTS - PREV_INPTS))" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 output.mkv
```

Following documentation may be helpful:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Expression-Evaluation

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#setpts